# i have two table one is of "users" table and "blockingUser" table, i need to select all users except those which a particular user blocked

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

blockUser table => _id , userId , blockedUserId

```
SELECT *
FROM User INNER JOIN
     blockUser 
     on User.userid = blockUser.blockedUserId where blockUser.userId='user1' and User.userId <> blockUser.blockedUserId;
```

one user can block more then one users.
I am getting error, please help me correct it.

Comment: `on where` is not SQL syntax.  Remove the `where`.

Comment: yeah thanks Gordon , i removed but still i did't get desired result, can you help me correct my query ?

Comment: Then ask another one.  In that question, include sample data and desired results.  If you can set up a SQL Fiddle, that is also helpful.  Someone has made an attempt to answer this question, so changing this question will probably invalidate his/her answer, and that can attract downvotes.

Comment: ohk, i will raise new question with more inputs .

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from user
left join  blockUser on user.userid = blockUser.userid
where Not exists user.userid = blockUser.blockedUserID
GroupBy(User.user_id)
```

this is all i can come up with from what you provided

Comment: xhulio, please check my new question from more inputs. thanks